# Just Cause 2 on Steam hanging on "Preparing to Launch"

Tags: steam, technical-issues, just-cause-2

I've been playing Just Cause 2 for a bit. I went a few days without switching on my desktop. I wanted to get back to playing the missions today, so I launched the game on Steam and it hangs on "Preparing to Launch."

From what I've googled around, people have recommended verifying local game cache. So I tried that, and thats hanging too!

Anybody have any ideas? Can I just reinstall the game without my progress disappearing? Any other potential remedies?

Comment: Since Just Cause 2 is a Steamworks game your saves should be safe in 'the cloud'. I haven't actually tested this yet, but whenever exiting the game I do see it syncing with the Steam server.

Comment: Now its hanging even on deleting local game content. This is getting frustrating.

Comment: I would say, check your system for hardware faults. Especially the memory the hard-drive. Accumulated dust might also be the (just) cause ;)

Comment: Have you rebooted your system in between? Maybe some process has files locked and thus prevents them from being accessed otherwise.

Comment: @Bora Its a new system so I doubt those are the issues. Other steam games seem to be working just fine in my library.  @mxp - thats a good idea. ill try it out right now. I hibernate the system most times.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks everyone. Rebooting did the trick. Thanks to mxp for the suggestion.