# What should I do if steam fails to launch a game?

Tags: steam

I've installed a few games everything worked flawless. After a while I couldn't any longer start Metro 2033. A message popup appears saying that Metro 2033 is launched the popup disappears and the game is NOT started.

What I've already tried:

1. [Reboot](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/15488/just-cause-2-on-steam-hanging-on-preparing-to-launch)
2. Reinstall the game -> Still having this issue.
3. Activate the game again -> Message: User already owns this product.
4. Checked the logfiles -> No hint about a crash or error messages.
5. [Steam Won't Launch - CMultifieldBlob(pSerialized)](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/75809/steam-wont-launch-cmultifieldblobpserialized)
6. Opened a ticket on the steam support site -> No response yet.

Does anyone have an idea how I could solve this issue?

What if more games become defective?

EDIT:

Now I see messages like this in C:\Program Files (x86)\Steam\debug.log

```
[0119/095917:ERROR:backend_impl.cc(2123)] Corrupt Index file
[0119/095917:ERROR:cache_util_win.cc(48)] Unable to move the cache: 5
[0119/095917:ERROR:backend_impl.cc(134)] Unable to move cache folder
[0119/095917:ERROR:backend_impl.cc(264)] Unable to create cache
```

7. [Verified integrity of game cache](https://www.carbongames.com/forums/viewtopic.php?f=10&t=4975)

Comment: By "reinstall" I suppose you mean Delete local content → Redownload/Restore backup?

Comment: Have you tried running the game as administrator?

Comment: @badp Yes, by using the games properties menu.

Comment: @Steinin No it worked before, the item in the start menu isn't linked to an executable but steam://rungameid/43110 I couldn't find a run as admin option there,

Comment: @Steinin I tried to run the exe as admin same effect.

Comment: Have there been any changes to the game or computer since the last time it worked? Software updates, driver updates, new graphics card etc?

Comment: @Steinin I installed another game via steam and countless usual Windows7 updates.

Comment: Unfortunately your ticket won't probably be responded to before Monday, 9 AM PST at least. Now is kind of the single worst time to make steam tickets. :)

Comment: Have you tried reinstalling Steam?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This appears to be a Steam problem, backup your data and reinstall Steam.

Answer (score 3):

You should try the following steps

- Close Steam
- Go to your steam installation folder
- Delete the ClientRegistry.blob file
- Start Steam again

Steam should show an upate message.
After that your game should work again

ps: you can rename the file to ClientRegistry.oldblob or something similiar if you dont want to delete it

If it's still not working try the following article in Steam Support section

[This game is currently unavailable](https://support.steampowered.com/kb_article.php?ref=4595-WEXN-6831)

Comment: k didn't see that xD